# Why the throughput of the same Jmeter project differ so much?

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to test load test my SpringBoot website. The website is deployed in our Linux server.

I tested in my local computer, the throughout is arond 500/sec. I copyed the Jmeter  package(including bin, doc...) and jmx file to my collegue's computer. He used the same Jmeter to run the same jmx project, but the through is always under 200/sec.

That is very confusing. We have the same jmx project, and load test the same website, why the throughout differs so much?

Edit: Or maybe the local computer environment will affect this. Do you know where? The JVM config or CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of at least 3 possible issues:

1. Different Java version. Make sure to have the same [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or [Server JRE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html) version
2. Different hardware specifications

   - CPU
   - RAM
   - NIC
3. Different operating system version/setup
4. Different network connectivity, i.e. if [you're connected via Ethernet and your colleague is sitting on Wi-Fi it might matter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter)

I would recommend setting up monitoring of:

1. JVM health status - you can do this using i.e. [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html)
2. OS health status - you can do this using built-in monitoring tools or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)